# listbox.js or pickers.js not loading from sv-se, Error 404

Tags: google-chrome, listbox, xpages, xpages-extlib

I have an XPage that I open from Google Chrome on my computer. it all looks good on my side. 
Google Chrome is displaying web pages by default in Swedish.

When my customer open the same webpage from their environment they get a lot of errors causing the webpage to not load properly.

I have noticed that when my customer is loading the webpage they get different locations of the listbox.js files.

Image show the errors my customer get

[image]

Below image show what it looks like on my side. working!

[image]

I am using Swedish language in Chrome but when I load the page it is not loading from the sv-se directory.

Why is my customer loading the files from the sv-se folder?

ExtLib version: 9.0.1.v00_16_20160128-1014

Server version: Release 9.0.1FP4|June 07, 2015 Windows/64

Comment: Do they have overzealous web filtering, proxies, or the like?

Comment: not sure, will check!

Answer (score 2):

From the screenshot, the customer's browser is attempting to load the NLS (natural language string) dojo JS files for the language `sv-se`:

```
http://...../xsp/.ibmxspres.extlib/dijit/nls/sv-se/listbox.js
```

No such language code is supported by Dojo, only `sv` is supported. The sv-se folder doesn't exist, hence the error. It seems sv-se is an alternate code for standard Swedish.

That's why it's working on your machine, as you are loading the `sv` NLS files:

```
http://...../xsp/.ibmxspres.extlib/dijit/nls/sv/listbox.js
```

**Further info:**
I don't see a way in Chrome to use language `sv-se`. But you can use it in Internet Explorer and Firefox, thus hitting the issue.

You can see the problem in the head of the page html, where it says `var dojoConfig = {locale: 'sv-se' ...`

I was able to fix this issue by opening the Application Properties -> XPages tab -> Enable localization -> Add "Swedish" to the list -> Save and re-build

[image]

In your case, it may make sense to make Swedish the Source and Default language too.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but why is my customer browser loading the file from the sv-se folder?

Comment: I do believe that this problem started after upgrading to latest extlib, but not 100% sure

Comment: Are they using Internet Explorer? I don't see a way to make `sv-se` the language in Chrome

Comment: Ok there must be a way to use it in Chrome too. I've added a potential fix/workaround, by enabling localisation on the app. This seems to resolve `sv-se` as `sv` for Dojo

Comment: ok, thanks but that made the whole application full of [sv] tags I need to translate. not a good solution.

Comment: hold on, I may have forgotten to set source language, let me try this again

Comment: Brian. that seem to have fixed it. Is this something that can/will be fixed in newer version of extlib?

Comment: If there is a fix in this area, it would be in dojo code, which is not part of ExtLib. So would only be added for Domino Next, or potentially a fix pack if it had a high escalation